# Using Threads to Update UI in Vaadin 14

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I created a thread (via a lambda expression) to fetch some data based on user input fields but when I try to click on dropdown menus while it is retrieving data I get the mini progress bar indicator. So is a new thread even being created? What am I doing wrong here?

```
Button doComputation = new Button("Get Results);
doComputation.addClickListener(event -> {
        UI ui = UI.getCurrent();
        new Thread(() -> {
             
             // Do some work
             ui.access(() -> layout.add(results);

        }).start();
});
```

UPDATE: RESOLVED! Unneccesary ui.access calls were made, which locked up resources. Thank you to all that commented and helped.

Comment: What is the actual problem? Is your layout not modified? Are you sure results has a sane value? Are there errors, logs, ...?

Comment: @cfrick the results are fine (no error logs) but while generating them, the input fields like comboboxes are unresponsive

Comment: @samwatts only when you make changes to a UI from another thread (and push them to the active session) should you call ui.access(). Any work being done in the background is just that - work. It does not entail accessing/updating the UI until something is being explicitly added (like a chart or Grid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks correct to me (apart from the missing end parenthesis after `ui.access`). Is that the only `ui.access` call, and is that all you do inside it?

I made this example for reference, and the combo box stays responsive while the background task is running.

```
@Route
public class ThreadView extends VerticalLayout {

    public ThreadView() {
        Button runThreadButton = new Button("Start thread", e -> {
            UI ui = UI.getCurrent();
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                ui.access(() -> Notification.show("Completed"));
            }).start();
        });
        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>("Items", "One", "Two", "Three");
        add(runThreadButton, comboBox);
    }
}
```

Comment: so I do have multiple ui.access calls, and there are some other things I've added in the thread including data parsing and reading/writing to files. so everything works except the concurrency

Comment: Two additional thoughts @samwatts: 
1) Is the stuff _within_ `ui.access()` taking a lot of time? 
2) Do the comboboxes access something that the computation (started by the button) might be blocking (i.e threads might be blocking on some other resource)?

Comment: @samwatts Have you enabled `@Push`?

Comment: @MarcEnglund depending on the input parameters a given data retrieval phase could take several minutes. your second suggestion to see if the thread is blocking resources is likely - although I have not yet pinpointed the exact step responsible

Comment: @MarcEnglund you were indeed correct - I made an unnecessary ui.access() call which locked the resource I needed to proceed!

Answer (score 1):

> So is a new thread even being created?

You can verify that by adding a `System.out.println("Thread started")` and checking whether that message is printed, or by running your application in debug mode and setting a breakpoint on the part that you're interested in.

> What am I doing wrong here?

The code that you showed looks fine. I would guess there's a problem outside the shown code, namely that you have forgotten that you also need to add the `@Push` annotation. Without that annotation, the server will have no way of directly sending messages to the client.

Comment: i have added the @Push annotation, and the outputs are being displayed correctly - however, while the computation is happening the input fields are unresponsive